# Call Google Finance Options API URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Typing this into the browser automatically downloads a txt file that is json formatted text of AAPL stock option data.

http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&output=json

I'd like to pull this data into a Javascript variable directly though, so I can parse the results and display the data in the browser.

I tried:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&output=json', function(json) {
      console.log(json);
    });
```

but I get the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error, as seen in other posts.

I tried with ajax as well:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&output=json",
}).done(function ( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

but get the same error.

I also tried with jsonp (`&output=jsonp`) in the url, but get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` error and it returns `();` in Chrome inspector.

How can I pull this json data from Google directly into JS?

Comment: try `https://` rather than `http://`

Comment: I no longer get the error, but no data is being pulled and nothing is getting printed in the console. Thanks

Comment: If you want to get the data, try to put success function in the Ajax object. After the Ajax return, it will go to success function not the done function. Ajax will execute the done function first, because it is an async method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do it... but it works.

First, to resolve the cross domain request you can use YQL.
Then, the url answer is not a valid json string. So I'm using "eval" to execute the response text and store it in the tmp variable.

```
function toYQL(site){
    return 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' +
        encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') +
        '&format=json&callback=?';
}
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: toYQL("http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&output=json"),
  success: function(response){
      eval("var tmp=" + response.query.results.body);
      console.log(tmp);
  }
})
```

There you go.

Comment: Your script can be hacked easily with SQL Injection and there is no need and no reason to use other api to call another api.

Comment: "I'm sure there's a better way to do it... but it works."
Then propose a solution